# Change high of listview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So i have 3 `ListView` inside one `StackLayout` but the i get an scroll in all of the `ListView` and I would like their height to depend on the number of items contained.

Here is my `xaml` file

```
 <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Ingredientes"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                </Label>
                <ListView x:Name="listaIngredientes"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ingredientes}"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>



            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Informacion dietetica"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                </Label>
                <ListView x:Name="informacionDietetica"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding especificacionesDieteticas}"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>



            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Informacion nutricional"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                </Label>
                <ListView x:Name="informacionNutricional"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding especificacionesSanitarias}"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding}">

                            </TextCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
```

I've tried wraping everything inside `ScrollView`, `AbsoluteLayout` and `RelativeLayout` but no one did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution , you can have a try .

If the number of `Cells` in the `ListView` can be determined and the height of each `Cell` is set, the height of the `ListView` can be calculated. At the same time, the height of the `ListView` can be dynamically modified as follows when the program is running.

```
listview.HeightRequest = CellCount * CellHeight;
```

Eg: the height of `listaIngredientes` listview  should be :

```
listaIngredientes.HeightRequest == YourViewModel.ingredientes.Count * CellHeight;
```

Comment: I get an error `CellCount doesnt exist in the actual context`

Comment: @JaimeCuellar Hi, `CellCount` is from the count of `ListView.ItemsSource`.

Comment: @JaimeCuellar I have updated answer .You can have a look when you have time.